# Resize input box to contents onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to get my input boxes [type='text'] to re-size to their content on page load. Using this code, they effectively re-size on **focus**.

`$(document).ready(function () {
       $("input[type='text']").bind('focus', function () {
       $(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length );
    });
});`

I have tried swapping 'focus' for different events such as 'load' and 'ready' to no avail. Please keep in mind I am looking for something lightweight and quick, that will re-size all input [type='text'] boxes to their content on page load.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3bwkcs8s/1/)

---

## Solution

I ended up using [Thom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2634948/thom) answer as the solution, but I then realized that I would also like the input box to expand as text is typed into it. So I combined what I had before and Thom's answer to provide both features. I also added css to make sure it doesn't size off the page. Here is my final code:

**HTML**
`<input type="text" value="resized onload and when typing"/>`

**jQuery**
`$(document).ready(function () {
       $("input[type='text']" ).each(function( index ) {
       $(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length + 5 );
    });
       $("input[type='text']").bind('keyup', function () {
       $(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length + 5);
    });
});`

**CSS**
`input[type="text"]{ max-width:100%;}`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/33jL8zrp/)

Comment: A potential solution is to change bind to load. It is not the best solution, but it works. https://jsfiddle.net/lexingtonpenguins/3bwkcs8s/2/

Comment: nice, that was quick. Can we clean it up a bit. Is there anything that can be removed?

Comment: load is deprecated, so maybe a cleaner way would be to make a foreach loop? http://jsfiddle.net/lexingtonpenguins/o6u3xaqr/

Comment: mhm i like that aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through them on dom ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("input[type='text']").each(function()
    {
        $(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bwkcs8s/7/)

Answer (score 1):

**If the value is set you can use this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('size', $(this).attr('value').length);
    });

});
```

**If you want to re-size during typing add this:**

```
$("input[type='text']").on('input', function () {
   $(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length );
   console.log($('input[type="text"]').attr('size'));
});
```

Remember the 'size' represents number of characters inside your inputs. The actual width depends on font-size you are using AND size of your input. (just for sure:)